# Name of the geometric figure of points ${\bf x} \in \Bbb R^n$ with $1$-norm $||{\bf x}||_1 = 1$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is there a name for the figure

> $$\{{\bf x} \in \Bbb R^n : ||{\bf x}||_1 = 1\} \subset \Bbb R^n ?$$

Things like this seem to usually have names, for instance, the *$n$-cube* or *$n$-ball*.

In $2$ dimensions it would simply be (the boundary of) a rotated square, and in $3$ dimensions a suitably positioned octahedron with 'radius' $1$.

Comment: This looks like a hyperplane to me ...

Comment: The unit ball in the 1-norm topology (by analogy with the usual unit ball with the Euclidean (2) norm)

Comment: I usually use the descriptive name "unit diamond". It's analogous to the unit ball and the unit square, but indicates the shape appropriately.

Comment: For $n = 3$ (in fact, for all $n > 1$), the edge length is $\sqrt{2}$, not $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The $n$-dimensional generalization of an octahedron is called [cross-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope).